# Looking for help with an inequality question involving calculus and logarithms

Tags: integration, inequality, logarithms

I've been stuck on this particular example question for a while now and was hoping that someone could shed some light on it. The question requires showing the inequality $$N\log_{}N-N<\log(N!)<(N+1)\log_{}(N+1)-N$$ by considering the area under the curves $y=\log_{}(x)$ and $y=\log_{}(x-1)$. My issue is with getting the $N!$ term in the middle. I began by fixing $N\in\mathbb{N}$ since the otherwise the log and factorial could be undefined. For the outer terms, I first noted by considering the graphs of the functions that clearly the area under $y=\log_{}(x-1)$ is less than $y=\log_{}(x)$. I then evaluated the indefinite integrals, $$\int\log_{}(x)dx=x\log_{}(x)-x(+C)$$ and $$\int\log_{}(x-1)dx=(x-1)\log_{}(x-1)-(x-1)(+C)$$ We can than write $$(N-1)\log_{}(N-1)-(N-1)<N\log(N)-N<N\log(N)+\log(N)+(N+1)\log(1)-N=(N+1)\log(N+1)-N$$ by the assumption $N\in\mathbb{N}$. I'm unsure of how to proceed from here though, so any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible that you mean $\log(N!)$ instead of $N!$ in the inequality? As currently stated, this inequality is not true.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I've edited the typo, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have $\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k}<e$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore,

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{2}{1}\right)^{1}&<e\\
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2}&<e\\
\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{3}&<e\\
&\ \vdots\\
\left(\frac{N+1}{N}\right)^{N}&<e\end{align*}$$

Multiplying all these inequalities gives
$$\frac{\left(N+1\right)^{N}}{N!}<e^{N}.$$
Taking logarithm on both sides, you can get a stronger result
$$N\log\left(N+1\right)-N<\log\left(N!\right).$$

The other side is similar by using $\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k+1}>e$.